# Uploading video to server with pure Swift, PHP code

Tags: php, ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to upload a video to a Godaddy server
using Swift and PHP.   I can send a "2 sec" video to the File Manager but any longer and it fails.

```
    // This function combining the unquie ID and the string -VIDEO.mov to make a file name for the  body.appendString in cresteBodyWithPramsVideo function.
func videoID () -> String{
    let unquieID =  theDictionary.value(forKey: "unquieID") as! String
    let filename = "-VIDEO.mov"
    let filename2 = "\(unquieID)" + "\(filename)"
    return filename2
}



func createBodyWithParamsVideo(_ parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: Data, boundary: String) -> Data {

    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }


    let mimetype = "video/mov"

    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(videoID())\"\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(imageDataKey)
    body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body as Data

}




func uploadVideo (){

    let unquieID  =  theDictionary.value(forKey: "unquieID") as! String

    // url path to php file
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.myWebSite.com/Video.php")!

    // declare request to this file
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    // declare method 
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // param to be sent in body of request
    let param = ["id" : unquieID]

    // body
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    // Issign video to videoData var
    let videoData = theDictionary.value(forKey: "theVideo") as! NSData

    // ... body
    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParamsVideo(param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: videoData as Data, boundary: boundary)

    // launch session
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let response = response {
        }

        // get main queue to communicate back to user
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {


            if error == nil {

                do {
                    // json containes $returnArray from php
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                    print(data!)
                    print(json!)

                    // declare new parseJSON to store json
                    guard let parseJSON = json else {
                        print("Error while parsing")

                        return
                    }

                    // get id from $returnArray["id"] - parseJSON["id"]
                    let id = parseJSON["id"]

                    // successfully uploaded
           if id != nil { 
           UserDefaults.standard.set(parseJSON, forKey: "parseJSON")
                    // unquieID = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "parseJSON") as? NSDictionary

                        // did not give back "id" value from server
                    } else {
                       //Do somthing
                        // get main queue to communicate back to user
                        // DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        // let message = parseJSON["message"] as! String
                        // appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                        //                        })

                    }

                    // error while jsoning
                } catch {

                    // get main queue to communicate back to user
                    //  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    ////  let message = error as! String

                    // appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                    //         })
                    //                   return
                }


                // error with php
            } else {

                // get main queue to communicate back to user
                // DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                ////   let message = error!.localizedDescription
                print("message")
                // appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                //       })
                // return
            }


        })

        }.resume()

}

//Creating protocol of appending string to var of type data
extension NSMutableData {
func appendString(string : String) {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,    allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

The PHP

```
<?php


//STEP 1. Check passed data to this php file
if (empty($_REQUEST['id'])) {
$returnArray["massage"] = "Missing required information";
return;
}


// Pass POST via htmlencryot and assign to $id
$id = htmlentities($_REQUEST['id']);



//STEP 2. Folder for uploaded Video.
$folder = "VBCVideo/";



//STEP 3. Move uploaded file
$folder = $folder . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $folder)) {
    $returnArray["status"] = "200";
    $returnArray["massage"] = "The Video file has been uploaded";
} else {
    $returnArray["status"] = "300";
    $returnArray["massage"] = "Error while uploading the Video";
}


// STEP 8. Feedback array to app user
echo json_encode($returnArray);

?>
```

Now that the Godaddy PHP.ini upload_max_filesize is corrected "see my comments below" the issue is much the same.  I can now upload a file that is up to 12sec long anything longer will not upload. where do I go from here.

Comment: Ok here's where I am at this point.  the PHP.ini file in Godaddy was set to 2m this is why the larger file would not upload.  I changed this by going to the cPanel at the bottom under the title Software clicking on Select PHP version next click on "up around the top right" Switch TO PHP Options and at the bottom you will find  upload_max_filesize change this to what size you need and save that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a PHP.ini file to the Godaddy FileDirector under the public_html.   GO to "+File" to create a new file and name it "php.ini"

Add these lines to the file and save.

max_execution_time = 120;

upload_max filesize = 60M;

post_max_size = 70M;